# Using a finally statement in python to print out how many times Ive have been through the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch-finally

I'm confused about about how to use the "finally" statement!

So the first time through the loop there is an error because of an attempted division by zero. However, I still want to print to the user that the loop executed.

The except clause should print a message to the user informing them that a division by zero was attempted.

The finally clause should print out how many times we have been through the loop.

This is what I have so far

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print(7/i)
    except ValueError:
        print("Value contents invalid.")
    finally:
        Finally message
```

Comment: You're almost there, just add a print statement to your finally statement...

Comment: But it says I should print how many times that the person went through the loop.. what does that mean??

Comment: Print the current iteration + 1....

Comment: WHy is it when I do for i in range(10):
         try:
        print(7/i)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("there is an error because of an attempted division by zero.")
    finally:
        print("You incorrectly entered a value 2 times")
the output is

Comment: there is an error because of an attempted division by zero.
You incorrectly entered a value 2 times
7.0
You incorrectly entered a value 2 times
3.5
You incorrectly entered a value 2 times
2.3333333333333335
You incorrectly entered a value 2 times
1.75
You incorrectly entered a value 2 times
1.4
You incorrectly entered a value 2 times
1.1666666666666667
You incorrectly entered a value 2 times
1.0

Comment: You have it hardcoded....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's divide your question into parts:

Part 1: print to the user that the loop executed. The except clause should print a message to the user informing them that a division by zero was attempted.

Part 2: The finally clause should print out how many times we have been through the loop.

Below is the answer. Note that additional indentation is required. Also, it should be ZeroDivisionError, not ValueError.

```
for i in range(10):        
    try:
        print(7/i)
    except ZeroDivisionError: # part 1
        print("Division by zero error.")
    finally:
        print("We've been through the loop ", i + 1, " times.") # part 2
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help, and welcome to Stackoverflow!